# load materials on objects in async methods

Tags: unity-game-engine

I would like to load some materials on some objects with a thread/async but stuff i've tried by now are not working:

```
Thread d = new Thread(new ThreadStart(loadMethod));
d.Start();
```

The materials don't get loaded at all.

How can i load materials on objects without affecting the flow of the app? Right now it kind of freezes for 1-2 seconds.

Comment: I'd be surprised if you could, you're subverting Unity's thread model and their API isn't thread safe.  You can't guarantee that when you're changing the material that the renderer wouldn't also be loading that data in to the OpenGL/DirectX context.

Comment: Like Jerdak said it won't work as long as you interact with the Unity API. You can of course use threads for calculations that do not call any Unity functions s. [Make background thread in unity3d](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959832/make-background-thread-in-unity3d)

Comment: It sounds like you're using giant uncompressed textures. You should check the texture's settings and make sure that you really need them to be that big.

Comment: Also, if you're loading many textures you could do it in a coroutine and only load a few per frame. http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Coroutines_26_Yield.html