# preload textures in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am modifying a material, that is applied to an object, by changing its texture but the problem is that i get some lag while doing this.

How can i preload some textures in memory to avoid temporal lag in unity3d?

Comment: This is very similar to your [other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974108/load-materials-on-objects-in-async-methods).

Comment: @Jerdak no it is not, in that post i was interested in loading images in async. In this, i am interested in preloading images.

Answer (score 5):

Are you loading the texture right before you add it? How is the new texture stored? Typically, pre-caching is done during the Awake() or Start() loops.

```
Renderer objectRenderer;
public Texture2D replacementTextureAsset;
Texture2D runtimeTextureReplacement;

void Awake()
{
  objectRenderer = (Renderer)GetComponent(typeof(Renderer));

  // Either have the texture assigned via the inspector (replacementTextureAsset above)
  //  or else get a reference to it at runtime. Either way, the texture will be loaded into memory by the end of this loop.
  runtimeTextureReplacement = Resources.Load("myReplacementAsset");
}

void TextureReplace()  // Called whenever
{
  objectRenderer.material.texture = replacementTextureAsset;

  OR

  objectRenderer.material.texture = runtimeTextureReplacement;
}
```

If this is what you're already doing and you still have "lag", then you're probably experience the inevitable consequence of sending the texture to the frame buffer on the graphics card. In that case, there's nothing you can do except use a smaller texture.

Answer (score 0):

I gave your question a little more thought and here is my suggestion, it's hacky and I wish I didn't have to associate this code with my name:

```
    public bool TextureCached = false;
public bool TextureLoaded = false;
public bool TextureLoadReady = false;
public string TexturePath = "";
public int MaxPixelConvert = 1000;

Texture2D cached_texture = null;
public Vector2 last_pixel = new Vector2(0,0);

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    SwapMainTexture();
    StartWorker();
}

void StartWorker(){
    Thread t1 = new Thread (new ThreadStart (this.ListenForUpdate));
    t1.Start();
}

/// <summary>
/// Reads new texture from TexturePath
/// </summary>
IEnumerator ReadNewTexture(){
    UnityEngine.WWW urltexture = new WWW(TexturePath);
    yield return urltexture;

    cached_texture = urltexture.texture;

    TextureLoadReady = false;
    TextureCached = true;
}
void ListenForUpdate(){
    // Simulate waiting for an asynchronous update notifying us of the updated texture.
    Thread.Sleep(1000); 

    // ...Receive some notification image is ready load.


    // In my case, I'm just loading a local file for testing.
    TexturePath = @"file://C:\Users\Public\Pictures\LargeAssPicture.jpg";
    TextureLoadReady = true;
}

/// <summary>
/// Create a temporary copy of maintexture so that SetPixel doesn't overwrite the original
/// </summary>
void SwapMainTexture(){
    Texture2D texture = (Texture2D)Instantiate(renderer.material.mainTexture);
    renderer.material.mainTexture = texture;
}

/// <summary>
/// Update the main texture in small chunks (<MaxPixelConvert)
/// </summary>
void ImABadIdea(){
    int count = 0;
    Texture2D main_texture = (Texture2D)renderer.sharedMaterial.mainTexture;
    for(int x = (int)last_pixel.x; x <= cached_texture.width; x++){
        for(int y = (int)last_pixel.y; y <= cached_texture.height; y++){
            main_texture.SetPixel(x,y,cached_texture.GetPixel(x,y));
            last_pixel = new Vector2(x,y);

            if(y+1>=cached_texture.height)last_pixel.y = 0;
            count += 1;
            if(count >= MaxPixelConvert)break;
        }
        if(count >= MaxPixelConvert)break;
    }
    main_texture.Apply();

    if(last_pixel.x == cached_texture.width && last_pixel.y == cached_texture.height){
        TextureLoaded = true;
    }
}

void Update () {
    if(TextureLoadReady){   //trigger when new texture ready to load
        TextureLoadReady = false;
        StartCoroutine(ReadNewTexture());
    }
    if(TextureCached && !TextureLoaded){    //trigger when new texture is loaded and start streaming it
        ImABadIdea();
    }
}
```

The texture load is triggered by a simple worker thread.  When the thread "receives" notification of a new texture to load it sets the appropriate flag (I know I'm not locking shared resources but my example is simple enough).  After that, the texture is sourced in to a cache and then gradually applied to my object's texture in small 1000px chunks each frame tick inside the main thread.

In my test scene I had my main object and then a clone of that object that remained hidden offscreen.  The clone had the script and would load the new texture.  When the texture was loaded, I swapped it in for the main object.

The code was tested on a 3000x3000 pixel image.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the texture in some way, it'll get uploaded to the graphics card. So, during your game's loading screen, you just need to loop through all the textures you want to 'preload,' and use them in some way - for example by rendering them to a RenderTexture, or using GUI.DrawTexture to draw them to the screen (and then draw your loading screen background on top).

Answer (score 0):

May be it`s not cool, but it works in Unity 5.3.
Call this extension method at awake/start scene/monobehaviour on every gameobject you want to have texture preloaded.

```
public static class GameObjectExtension
    {
        public static void PreloadTexture( this GameObject go )
        {
            var render = go.GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>();
            if ( render && render.sharedMaterial && render.sharedMaterial.mainTexture )
            {
                int dd = render.sharedMaterial.mainTexture.width;
            }
        }
    }
```

The idea taken from [here.](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/texture-awakefromload.69730/#post-446829)